Minimum number of elements in all sets
I have an interesting problem:
Several (K) people go to the bookstore to buy books. Each person buys four (different) (more generally, m) books, and every two people share exactly (only) two (more generally, n, where 1 ≤ n ≤ m) of the same books. Now, what is the minimum number of kinds of books that can meet these conditions?
For 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 people with two shared books, we can use a construction method to create the sets as follows:

Case with 2 People

A =   {1, 2, 3, 4}
B =   {1, 2, 5, 6}


Case with 3 People

A =   {1, 2, 3, 4}
B =   {1, 2, 5, 6}
C =   {3, 4, 5, 6}


Case with 4 People

A =   {1, 2, 3, 4}
B =   {1, 2, 5, 6}
C =   {1, 3, 5, 7}
D =   {1, 4, 6, 7}


Case with 5 People

A =   {1, 2, 3, 4}
B =   {1, 2, 5, 6}
C =   {1, 3, 5, 7}
D =   {1, 4, 6, 7}
E =   {2, 3, 6, 7}


Case with 6 People

A =   {1, 2, 3, 4}
B =   {1, 2, 5, 6}
C =   {1, 3, 5, 7}
D =   {1, 4, 6, 7}
E =   {2, 3, 6, 7}
F =   {2, 4, 5, 7}


Case with 7 People

A =   {1, 2, 3, 4}
B =   {1, 2, 5, 6}
C =   {1, 3, 5, 7}
D =   {1, 4, 6, 7}
E =   {2, 3, 6, 7}
F =   {2, 4, 5, 7}
G =   {3, 4, 5, 6}



So, for 2 and 3 people, we need 6 kinds of books; for 4, 5, 6, and 7 people, we need 7 kinds of books.
For K >= 8 people, it seems that constructing the sets becomes much more challenging.
One possible solution is:
Fix the shared two kinds of books the same between every two people, then the remaining two books of every person must be different. So the final result is:

2 + K * 2 = 2K + 2

This is indeed the general right construction, and I suspect this is indeed the minimum construction (if K > 7). However, I cannot find any mathematical proof to confirm this or deny this.
So, does anyone have the right answer?
For a more general problem:
K people go to the bookstore to buy books. Each person buys M different books, and every two people share exactly N (where 1 ≤ N ≤ M) of the same books. Now, what is the minimum number of kinds of books that can meet these conditions?
A general construction is like the following:

N + (M - N) * K



So, is it possible to get an algorithm to construct and verify the problem, and then find the minimum construction?
Is there an general method/formula to get the miminum number?
Are formula (1) & (2) the miminum or not? What's the right answer?


This is a type of combinatorial designs, and those can be tricky. At first glance I don't see this particular type of design on that wiki page though.

@JaapScherphuis I think this is a pairwise balanced design if you view each block as the set of people that bought each book.

This question was also asked on math.SE here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4991184/715329


So, is it possible to get an algorithm to construct and verify
the problem, and then find the minimum construction?

To approach the problem systematically, I have had
to ask the question in the opposite direction.
In fact, below I show an algorithm that systematically finds
solutions in that space [though it's work in progress, see below:
which is the main reason why I am posting here, not in Mathematics].
I am not and probably will not be able to go from there to closed
counting formulas, if it is possible at all, but someone else might
be able to build/improve on it.
The (opposite) question
For L,M,N,K (non-negative) integers,
with 0<=N<=M<=L and 0<=K, where:

L is the number of book titles available;
M is the number of books every customer buys;
N is the number of equal book titles
every two customers buy;
K is the number of customers served.

Given L,M,N, find max(K), i.e. the maximum
number of customers that can be served.
Preliminary inspection
A preliminary inspection reveals that
the only interesting case is 0<N<M<L.

Case 0=N=M <= L => [].
// no buying => no buys (i.e. no served)

Case 0=N < M <= L => [[1..M],[M+1..2M],...,[(k-1)M+1..kM]]
// no matches, buy some => argmax{k}(kM<=L) buys

Case 0 < N=M <= L => [[1..M],[1..M],...]
// all matches, buy some => infinitely many identical buys

Case 0 < N < M=L => [[1..M]].
// N<M matches, buy all => 1 buy

Case 0 < N < M < L => ...non-trivial...
// N<M matches, buy M<L => finitely many distinct buys


An algorithmic solution
Here is an algorithm that systematically explores the solution
space for the case 0<N<M<L: presented in a logic programming
style [i.e. the best I have been able to do for now].
Specifically, given 0<N<M<L, up to relabelling of book titles and
customers [not sure if 100% correctly], this procedure generates
in sequence all the possible customer buys filled to the maximum
number of customers that can be served for the subsequent choices
the customers make.
--dom:
0. Given 0 < N < M < L:
--base 1:
1. For person k = 1:
  101. Pick the buy B1 := [1,2,...,M].        (WLOG:fixed)
  102. Let S := [M+1,...,L] be the remaining available titles.
--loop 1: (until it fails)
2. For each person k > 1 up to failure:
  --pre 2:
  201. Let [C1,...,C{k-1}] := clone([B1,...,B{k-1}]) be
       the cloned previous buys, for later *marking*.
  202. Let Q := [] be the books *picked* by k.
  203. Let R := [] be the books *excluded* for k.
  --loop 2:
  21. For each Ci, with 1 <= i < k:
    --pre 3:
    211. Mark elements of R in Ci as excluded.
    21201. Let qi := the number of books marked picked in Ci.
    21202. Let si := the number of unmarked books in Ci.
    2121. If qi > N: FAIL!                                ^^REDO^^
    2122. If N-qi > si: FAIL!                             ^^REDO^^
    213. Add N-qi unmarked books of Ci to Q.  (WLOG:l2r)  [CHOICE]
    214. Add any remaining unmarked books of Ci to R.
    --loop 3:
    215. If N-qi > 0 (else do nothing):
      2151. For each Ci', with i <= i' < k:
        21511. Mark elements of Q in Ci' as picked.
        21512. Mark elements of R in Ci' as excluded.
        21513. If the number of books marked picked in Ci' is N:
          215131. Add any remaining unmarked books of Ci' to R.
          215132. (Mark the remaining unmarked books of Ci' as excluded.)
  --post 2:
  220. Let q := the number of books in Q.
  221. If q > M: FAIL!                                    ^^REDO^^
  222. If q < M:
    2220. Let s := the number of books in S.
    2221. If M-q > s: FAIL!                               ^^REDO^^
    2222. Move M-q books from S to Q.         (WLOG:l2r)  [CHOICE]
  223. If B{k-1} > Q: FAIL!                   (WLOG:asc)  ^^REDO^^
  224. Pick the buy Bk := Q.
--end 1: (loop 1 has failed)
3. YIELD [B1,...,B{k-1}].

Some results
An implementation in SWI-Prolog under GPLv3+ is
available on my Gist.
Here are some results (slightly reformatted by hand for readability):
e.g. for M=4, N=2, a minimum of L=20 available book titles is needed
for K=9 people to get served:
[Ideally the procedure should generate solutions in reverse order of
length, but that does not work yet: e.g. try pairwise_tt(5, 3, 2).
So, these results are more illustrative than anything else...]
?- pairwise_t(20, _, 4, 2, [f]).
 (5,4,2) => [[1,2,3,4]]  (1)
 (6,4,2) => [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,5,6],[3,4,5,6]]  (3)
 (7,4,2) => [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,5,6],[1,3,5,7],
             [1,4,6,7],[2,3,6,7],[2,4,5,7],[3,4,5,6]]  (7)
 (8,4,2) => [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,5,6],[1,2,7,8],
             [1,3,5,7],[1,3,6,8],[1,4,5,8],[1,4,6,7]]  (7)
 (9,4,2) => [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,5,6],[1,2,7,8],
             [1,3,5,7],[1,3,6,8],[1,4,5,8],[1,4,6,7]]  (7)
(10,4,2) => [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,5,6],[1,2,7,8],[1,2,9,10]]  (4)
(11,4,2) => [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,5,6],[1,2,7,8],[1,2,9,10]]  (4)
(12,4,2) => [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,5,6],[1,2,7,8],[1,2,9,10],[1,2,11,12]]  (5)
(13,4,2) => [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,5,6],[1,2,7,8],[1,2,9,10],[1,2,11,12]]  (5)
(14,4,2) => [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,5,6],[1,2,7,8],
             [1,2,9,10],[1,2,11,12],[1,2,13,14]]  (6)
(15,4,2) => [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,5,6],[1,2,7,8],
             [1,2,9,10],[1,2,11,12],[1,2,13,14]]  (6)
(16,4,2) => [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,5,6],[1,2,7,8],
             [1,2,9,10],[1,2,11,12],[1,2,13,14],[1,2,15,16]]  (7)
(17,4,2) => [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,5,6],[1,2,7,8],
             [1,2,9,10],[1,2,11,12],[1,2,13,14],[1,2,15,16]]  (7)
(18,4,2) => [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,5,6],[1,2,7,8],[1,2,9,10],
             [1,2,11,12],[1,2,13,14],[1,2,15,16],[1,2,17,18]]  (8)
(19,4,2) => [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,5,6],[1,2,7,8],[1,2,9,10],
             [1,2,11,12],[1,2,13,14],[1,2,15,16],[1,2,17,18]]  (8)
(20,4,2) => [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,5,6],[1,2,7,8],[1,2,9,10],
  [1,2,11,12],[1,2,13,14],[1,2,15,16],[1,2,17,18],[1,2,19,20]]  (9)
true.


That was some three full days of work already: I don't regret it, but I am not sure if I should keep going, is there any interest?  In particular, are we maybe getting to some specific and useful "combinatorial design"?

In its generality this does not in fact seem to be one of the combinatorial designs mentioned by Wikipedia.

If we impose the additional constraint that all L book titles get bought, this becomes the problem of partitioning a set of size L into a collection of K subsets each of size M such that every two subsets share exactly N elements: and the solution space becomes quite simpler.  -- This can be obtained in my code by changing the second clause of pairwise__loop_1 to pairwise__loop_1(_, _, Bs0, [], Bs0)..

Other variations on the problem are possible, just overall I am inclined to think that a clean solution here can be hoped for only if the problem is stated more stringently.
